# Using Powershell to copy large Oracle table to SQL Server - memory issue

Tags: sql, oracle, powershell, sqlbulkcopy

We are trying to copy data from a large Oracle table (about 50M rows) to SQL Server, using Powershell and SQLBulkCopy. The issue with this particular Oracle table is that it contains a CLOB field and it seems that unlike other table loads, this one is taking up more and more OS memory, eventually overpowering SQL Server, which is located on the same server, on which Powershell is running. Oracle is external and data is being sent via a network. Max size of CLOB is 6.4M bytes, whereas the average size is 2000.

Here is a snip of code being used. Seems that batchsize does not have any bearing on what's happening:

`
$SourceConnection = New-Object Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client.OracleConnection($SourceConnectionnectionstring)
$SourceConnection.Open()

```
$SourceCmd = $SourceConnection.CreateCommand()
$SourceCmd.CommandType = "text"
$SourceCmd.CommandText = $queryStatment

$bulkCopy = New-Object Data.SqlClient.SqlBulkCopy($targetConnectionString, [System.Data.SqlClient.SqlBulkCopyOptions]::UseInternalTransaction)
$bulkcopy.DestinationTableName = $destTable 
$bulkcopy.bulkcopyTimeout = 0 
$bulkcopy.batchsize = 500

$SourceReader = $SourceCmd.ExecuteReader()
Start-Sleep -Seconds 2
$bulkCopy.WriteToServer($SourceReader)
```

`

We tried different batch sizes, smaller and larger, with same result.
Tried enableStreaming 1 / 0
tried using Internal Transaction (in the code sample above) or just using default options, but still specifying batch size...

Anything else we can try to do to avoid the memory pressure?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Turned out, after extensive research, an obscure Oracle command attribute is responsible for sending data for CLOBs, which is what was saturating memory.

**InitialLOBFetchSize**

This property specifies the amount of data that the OracleDataReader initially fetches for LOB columns. It is defaulted to 0, which means "the entire CLOB".

I set it to 1M bytes, which is plenty, and the process never ate into memory.